# how to set a background-image clickable only at particular section in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

"Start Free Trail" section alone should be clickable and also I want to add cursor pointer for the same

[image: "Start Free Trail" section alone should be clickable and also I want to add cursor pointer for the same]

Comment: at least search for some time. there are so many questions available for the same.

---------------------

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535722/making-part-of-an-image-clickable

---

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link

----------------------------

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375747/link-on-certain-position-of-an-image-background-which-is-responsive

----------------------------

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323883/can-a-specific-part-of-a-picture-be-used-as-a-link-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making part of an image clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535722/making-part-of-an-image-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy you don't even need js for that:

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 229px;
}
.img a { 
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  min-width: 230px;
  min-height: 34px;
  max-height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 184px;
  left: 34px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.img a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <a href="test.html"></a>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9caWD.jpg">
</div>
```